# How can I display which tower (Towerid, Location) was used by customer XX to make their first call?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I cannot get the result for the first call from a specific customer. I can get the result for all the calls from this specific customer.

```
Table 1: Tower: TowerID, Location
Table 2: Connect: Tower ID, CallsID
Table 3: Calls: CallsID, MoBileID, CallDate
Table 4: Mobile: MobileID, CustomerID
```

I expected to have the first call for a customer XX, Towerid, Location

Comment: Order by CallDate and get the first result only

Answer (score 0):

You can use `partition by` in this case. I've not tested the below query but I hope it works.

```
select temp.CustomerId, t.TowerId, t.Location
from Tower t 
    join Connect c on t.TowerId = c.TowerId 
    join (
        select CustomerId
         , CallsId
         , row_number() over (partition by CustomerId order by CallDate) rank
         from Calls c
             join Mobile m on c.MobileId = m.MobileId
    ) temp on temp.CallsId = c.CallsId and rank = 1
```